# How to use JWT(fetched from an API) on the client side

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am working with a 3rd party API(TMDB) to create a web app. The issue that I am facing is with authentication and sessions. The API requires the users to be authenticated as:
Step 1: Create a request token
Step 2: Ask the user for permission to approve the generated token.(https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/%7BREQUEST_TOKEN%7D
)
Step 3: Create a session ID with the request token that has been approved by the user in step 2. This session ID is used to write all the user related data(like posting ratings) and is meant to be kept as a secret.

So, I can easily generate a session ID but the problem that I am facing is that I just can't find a way to keep this session ID secured inside my application to use it later for doing some user related actions like posting ratings for a movie. Also, I just don't know how can I keep my users logged in to my application with that session ID.
Please help !

Comment: A simple google search will give you a plethora of examples. Please do at least attempt some research before simply asking for an answer. A good start would be: https://medium.com/swlh/a-practical-guide-for-jwt-authentication-using-nodejs-and-express-d48369e7e6d4

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways how to store jwt on client sides:

**1) cookie** - jwt is automatically contained in every request to server

**2) localStorage** (sessionStorage) - you should get jwt from storage and attach to server requests

There are a lot of articles about implementation of jwt on both sides.

If you want to know more about security and storages read [this good article](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)